# Spliting text on base of Carriage return in Excel sheet that shows diiferent behaviours for different methods

Tags: regex, vbscript

Have a excel sheet with a cell having data as given below

Cell1:

> Introduction and Basic wording
>   1, 3. A steps 1 and 3
>   - A sub-step 1 of 1.
>   - A sub-step 2 of 1
>   ...
>   2. A step 2.
>   - A sub-step 1 of 2
>
> 4, 6. A step 4 and 6
>   5. A step 5

**Note**: Few steps has full stop(".") at end

**Expected**- Want to split text base on steps(not on sub-steps). Introduction and basic wording should come along with Cell1

Cell1-

> Introduction and basic wording
>   1, 3. A steps 1 and 3
>   - A sub-step 1 of 1.
>   - A sub-step 2 of 1   ...

Cell2-

> 2. A step 2.
>
>    - A sub-step 1 of 1

Cell3-

> 4, 6. A step 3 and 6

cell4

> 5. A step 5

Below are the methods which gave me different result

**Method 1**: Using Crriage return(Chr(10))

```
If InStr(1, str, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
   arrVars = Split(str, Chr(10))
...
End If
```

**Result**: spliting each text like below

Cell1:

> 1, 3. A steps 1 and 3

Cell2:

> - A sub-step 1 of 1.

Cell3:

> ...

**Method 2**:Using regular expression

```
re.Pattern = "^\d[\.]?[, \d\.]? ([\s\S]*?)\r$"  
Set oCol = re.Execute(str)  
For Each sMtch In oCol  
  sStep = Trim(sMtch.SubMatches(0))  
...  
Next
```

**Result:** 0 matching

**Method 3**:Using regular expression splitting on Full-stop(".")

```
re.Pattern = "^\d[\.]?[, \d\.]? ([\s\S]*?)\.$"
```

**Result**:

Cell1:

> 1, 3. A steps 1 and 3
>   - A sub-step 1 of 1.
>   ...
>   Cell2:

**Method 4**:Using regular expression to include the pre-text before step one

```
"(?:^[\s\S]?|[\r\n])(\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*?)(?=[\r\n]+\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*|$)"
```

**Result**: 
Pre-text before to Step 1 is not included

Comment: Try [`(?:^|[\r\n])(\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*?)(?=\n\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/aE5uY1/1) regex (`.Global = True`, `.Multiline = False`, access `.Submatches(1)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:^|[\r\n])(\d+(?‌​:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*?)(?=‌​\n\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC3dK5/1)

Make sure you use `.Global = True`, `.Multiline = False` and access `.Submatches(1)` (the contents of the first capturing group).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:^|[\r\n]+)` - a non-capturing group with 2 alternatives, either the start of string or line break chars
- `(\d+(?‌​:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*?)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?‌​:, *\d+)?` - an optional sequence: `,`, followed with 0+ spaces and 1+ digits
  - `\.[\s\S]*?` - a dot (`\.`) and then 0+ any chars, as few as possible
- `(?=‌[\r​\n]+\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.|$)` - a positive lookahead requiring an end of string `$` or

  - `[\r\n]+` - linebreak (1 or more CR or LF symbols)
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:, *\d+)?` - see above
  - `\.` - a dot.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for your valuable comments and step wise explanation for the answer. It work for me.. only changes i did in your given code is '.Value' instead of '.Submatches(1)',since while executing in VBscript editor it is giving error as Exception:Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: Well, the point about Submatches means the value you need is captured into Group 1 and must be accessed via submatches.

Comment: Thats true for using Submatches. But here your code does not require to explictly tell group 1, since group 0 is non-capturing group and group 2 is a positive look ahead group.

Comment: A noncapturing group still consumes a newline. I agree you can use `Trim()` on the `.Value`.

Comment: Thanks. That one i am using on .Value to get a proper result.

Comment: I tried below code in Step 4 for above modification in requirement(where step 1 might have some pre-text), but i am failing to get the correct result. Can you please correct me?

Comment: I wonder if you just want to match a line/lines before the bullet item? Try [`(?:^|[\r\n])((?:(?!\d).*\r?\n)*\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*?)(?=[\r\n]+\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/eC3dK5/2).

Comment: I want to match a line(might be multiple sentences,come before step 1) before the bullet item

Comment: That is not possible with the regex in VBA, you need to either use the regex above, or when you iterate over the matches, before getting the first submatch, check the match index, and if it is not at the start of the string, append the substring up to that index to the first submatch.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion, which helps me to dig more on the issue. Let me understand the previous explanation. ` (?:^|[\r\n])((?:(?!\d).*\r?\n)*\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.[\s\S]*?)(?=[\r\n]+\d+(?:, *\d+)?\.|$)` . Here `**(?:(?!\d).*\r?\n)**`, negative look ahead will work only when there are no numeric number in the per-text.  **Q1.** If pre-text contain  _Introduction of step 1 and Basic wording_   **Q2.** If all my steps are in alphabetic(e.g. a) , b) , etc.) instead of numeric(e.g. 1. , 2. etc.),then workaround for this what i wd expect in regExp: negative look ahead `(?!a\)).*\n)`